# Why does there exist a totally positive element?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Given a totally real number field $K_0$ and its totally imaginary quadratic extension $K$. Does there exist an element $\psi\in O_K$ such that $-\psi^2$ is totally positive in $K_0$? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 
Since $K/K_0$ is  a quadratic extension, there exists $\alpha\in K^\times_0$ such that   $K=K_0(\sqrt{\alpha})$.

Claim: $\alpha$ must be "totally negative", which means $-\alpha$ is totally positive.

Otherwise, there is an embedding $\sigma:K_0 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sigma(\alpha)>0$. Then $\sigma$ can extend to an embedding $\widetilde{\sigma} : K\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $\widetilde{\sigma}(\sqrt{\alpha})=\sqrt{\sigma(\alpha)}$, note that $\widetilde{\sigma}$ is a real embedding. This is contradicted to that $K$ is totally imaginary.
Choose $\psi=\sqrt{\alpha}$, then $-\psi^2=-\alpha$ is totally positive.